# Не работает getline

Tags: c++, visual-c++, getline

Коллеги, добрый день, создаю новый вопрос, так как ответа на стэковерфлоу не нашёл, похожие темы не содержат такой же проблемы, как у меня, а на просторах интернета вообще нет информации по этому поводу, не работает getline, Visual Studio 2022 подчёркивает красным, я так понимаю эта функция устарела, тогда что использовать вместо неё? std::getline тоже пробовал, не работает, так как std не содержит такого члена. Если без std, то идентификатор getline не определен.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Human 
{
public:
    std::string name;
    std::string sex;
    std::string colorofhair;
    std::string colorofskin;
    int age;
    int weight;
    int height;
};

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251 > null"); // Решает проблему со считыванием русских букв
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    Human firstHuman;

    firstHuman.name = "Андрей";
    firstHuman.age = 21;
    firstHuman.sex = "Мужчина";
    firstHuman.colorofhair = "Чёрный";
    firstHuman.colorofskin = "Белый";
    firstHuman.weight = 67;
    firstHuman.height = 185;

    while (true)
    {
        std::string value;
        std::cout << "Введите свойство, которое вы хотите узнать?: ";
//      std::cin >> value; // Считывает только то, что идет до первого пробела
        getline(std::cin, value); // Требует подключение библиотеки <string>

        if (value == "Имя" || value == "имя")
        {
            std::cout << "Имя человека: " << firstHuman.name << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Возраст" || value == "возраст")
        {
            std::cout << "Возраст человека: " << firstHuman.age << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Пол" || value == "пол")
        {
            std::cout << "Пол человека: " << firstHuman.sex << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Цвет волос" || value == "цвет волос")
        {
            std::cout << "Цвет волос человека: " << firstHuman.colorofhair << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Цвет кожи" || value == "цвет кожи")
        {
            std::cout << "Цвет кожи человека: " << firstHuman.colorofskin << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Вес" || value == "вес")
        {
            std::cout << "Вес человека: " << firstHuman.weight << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Рост" || value == "рост")
        {
            std::cout << "Рост человека: " << firstHuman.height << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Ничего" || value == "ничего" || value == "Стоп" || value == "стоп" || value == "Не хочу" || value == "не хочу")
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "К сожалению такого свойства у этого человека нет." << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так "подчеркивает красным", "не компилируется" или "не работает"? "Машина не едет" - это может быть поломка, отсутствие бензина, или вы просто забыли ключ... И как вам помогать без информации?

Comment: cin >> value; так надо Вы же cout используете, то и cin используйте тоже

Comment: @Виктор Ну вот зачем ерунду говорить? Там же есть строки с пробелами! Введите так "Цвет волос", посмотрим...

Comment: Тогда смотреть для стринг: getline(stream, string, separator);

Comment: `std :: getline`

Comment: Есть подозрение, что подчёркивает т.к. ждёт `std::getline`

Comment: И std::getline пробовал, всё так же подчеркивает красным, так как std не содержит такого члена

Comment: А с `#include <string>`?

Comment: [cppreference getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) включает `#include <string>#include <iostream>#include <sstream>` - попробуйте

Comment: Странно, тут ваш код без проблем выполняется: https://onlinegdb.com/fvAFD0FlR (несчитая кракозябр, но тут особенности кодировок). Кст, ожидал, что у вас могут быть проблемы из-за использования русских букв в тексте и при считывании: буквы в тексте имеют кодировку файла, а то, что вводим из консоли тоже имеют свою кодировку и они могут не совпадать

Comment: Проблема кракозябр решается функцией setlocale, я думаю Вы с ней знакомы, в моем коде она есть, если не знакомы) А проблема с считыванием русских букв решается функцией system("chcp 1251 > null"); :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::getline требует подключения

```
#include <string>
```

Он там определен.

Comment: LoL
Спасибо, нигде ни капли информации об этом не было.

Comment: @SALUTE, как же «не было»? вот ввожу я в поисковой строке яндекса строку «std::getline», первой ссылкой получаю [такую](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), а там первой же строкой написано: «Defined in header <string>». ну и ниже даже пример приведён.

Comment: Да, я не уточнил, в рунете этой информации не было, либо я плохо искал.